# View-based NSTableView with floating group rows

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

This is actually a pretty simple question: Is there any way of making a group row's view on a view-based NSTableView float *without making it also transparent*?

Comment: which method did you override in the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom cell that draws however you like - the floating is only placing the cell inside the table.

Normally the RowView draws the bg for all cells, the default ones dont draw any own background. that is what you have to do in your cell -- have it draw a bg on its own and not rely on the TableRowView

Comment: I haven't tried it, but making a custom NSTableRowView (and setting its row to be floating) and drawing my custom background doesn't make the view opaque, I think.

Comment: I am sorry. I subclassed NSTableRowView and made it draw my own background and it does stay opaque when floating. Thanks.

Comment: i still don't understand how to get rid of the transparent subview

Comment: ? this isn't about getting rid of a subview. this is about having a background that stays opaque all the time -- and for that you have to provide a custom RowView :)

Comment: What method are we supposed to override in the subclass.. could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Override -drawBackgroundInRect: and do your own thing. You might also override -isOpaque to return YES, which can dramatically speed up drawing since the system knows it doesn't have to composite/blend translucent/transparent layers. See the docs for other properties / drawing overrides if your group row can be selected or a drop target.